# Does Vela the Night-Clad’s effect affect creature tokens?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was going to cast [Vela the Night-Clad](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Vela%20the%20Night-Clad) after I had a bunch of creature tokens to cause them to have intimidate.

Would this work the way I expect, or does the effect not apply to them?

Answer (score 6):

Vela's text says

> Other creatures you control have intimidate.

Creature tokens are creatures, so yes, Vela will give intimidate to creature tokens you control. (Except for itself, of course, if your Vela happens to be a token - but it has intimidate anyway so that doesn't matter.)

If the ability weren't supposed to apply to tokens, it would say "Other nontoken creatures you control have intimidate."